# Why is my pandas bar chart not symetrical

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I'm running this code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series([-0.049, 0.039, 0.002, -0.165]).plot(kind='bar')
```

and getting this:

[image: AsymetricalBar]

Why are the bars not centered with the plot area?

-piR

Update:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series([-0.049, 0.039, 0.002, -0.165]).plot(kind='bar', xlim=(-1, 4))
```

gets me:

[image: SymetricalBar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that is not the default behavior of matplotlib plots. By default, the axis limits are fit automatically to the shape of the data. You can set the limits yourself; just pass `ylim=(foo,bar)` to the `plot` method.